# How to add JS to Wordpress and reference CSS or other scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

so I am working on a custom theme in Wordpress. I used to have a whole lot of JS in the ***head.php***, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.widgetblock').accordion({
        //args
    });


    if ( have_posts() ) {
        //stuff
    }
});
```

However I've since read that the proper way to add JS in Wordpress is to use `wp_enqueue_script()` in ***functions.php***, so I'm trying to do that. What I've done is just put that same code into a .js file that I've save in the corresponding folder, and I'm then loading it like this:

```
function script_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js-code', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/js-code.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-widget' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_assets' );
```

I've added JQuery and JQuery UI as dependencies.

However, that doesn't work. Chrome says that accordion() and have_posts() aren't defined. I also encounter issues if I try to reference specific elements from my CSS.

So, what am I to do? This is probably a very basic problem, but I can't find how to solve it.

Another problem is, how do I make 100% sure that some JS scripts are loaded after the CSS? I'm using [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) which should be loaded right after it, but I'm not sure that's possible with wp_enqueue...
EDIT: I can't really load that script in the footer, it needs to be loaded immediately after the CSS. :/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well someone else posted an answer but then deleted it so...

The dependency I was using here `wp_enqueue_script( 'js-code', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/js-code.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-widget' ) );` was wrong; I should have used jquery-ui-accordion, which jquery-ui-widget doesn't include. I elected to include the whole of jquery-ui (so I could use other features without having to add specific dependencies for each of them) but to do that I had to link to Google's, since there is no full package in WP.

That fixed some of my issues, not everything (the -prefix-free script still isn't loaded right after the stylesheet, and I have to find a way to replace the PHP functions that I used before) but the website's working, so there's that :)

Thanks to whomever actually answered, I don't remember your username, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I have had to add jQuery to a WordPress site I use this code that I found on [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/)

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
 function my_jquery_enqueue() {
 wp_deregister_script('jquery');
 wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false,    null);
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

For what I understand, once you load jQuery this way you prevent conflicts and it gets loaded only once.